# PHP - Listen to POST request

Tags: php, rest

**EDITED QUESTION:** I want to simulate two different applications. On the first (script X) a form can be submitted and gets handled by itself. He also is POSTing data to a second application (script Y) via REST.

Currently script Y is nothing more then:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
 deliver_response(200, "success", $_POST);
}

function deliver_response($status, $status_message, $data) {
 header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
 $response['status'] = $status;
 $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
 $response['data'] = $data;

$json_response = json_encode($response);
 echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

So, when I submit script X, it is POSTing some data to script Y via REST, and above shows how script Y handles the POST request from script X. The **echo** is being displayed on the screen of script X, but I want to have a second screen with script Y where this echo is being displayed ***automatically*** **at the moment it receives the POST request from script X**.

I hope I made my point clear. Is this somehow possible that script Y just receives the POST request (maybe still sending 200 succes back), but also displays the data it received on it's own screen? If yes, could you give me a hint?

And no, I don't want for script Y to check every few seconds with a GET request if there was submitted some new data at script X.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are doing it in the browser the action should take you to script Y in the browser unless you are using some javascript to handle the request.

Comment: @CameronSpanos, well the form is handled in script X. Then I send the data from script X to script Y with REST. This is to simulate 2 different applications.

Comment: Have you looked into using ajax?

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax you could also do an easy fix with refreshing the page every so often with PHP

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the page you could use ajax. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

You could also do a refresh on page Y with PHP

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I mean. I editted my whole question to clarify the problem more. I hope it's more clear now!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same situation some time ago when an external API was to send data on a result URL being hosted at our server. I think you have same issue, just the sender and receiver are both hosted by you.

Script Y must have `$recieved_params= file_get_contents(php://input)`
This will capture everything posted to this script, then you can process the contents.

Since this page is called by a script, not your browser,it won't just echo stuff, you can redirect your browser when `$recieved_params` isn't empty.